# What would you call an entity that is indestructible, but harmless to others?(read statement)

Tags: single-word-requests

I know the film *Hancock* is fiction, but I still can't help but wonder if there is a word that describes how, although he tossed that boy hundreds of feet in the sky, the boy had no damage done to his belly when he landed on top of Hancock's shoulder. For those who don't know, Hancock is an invincible guy who can also fly and has super strength.

Is there a word to refer to Hancock's unique ability as described here?

Comment: "Surviving anywhere" and "not being injured by extreme trauma / assault" are... very different things.  Can you convey your target a bit more clearly?

Comment: What does it mean for an object to "survive"? There's a criterion for living beings -- they've survived if they're still alive -- but how do you tell if a random physical object has survived?

Comment: We don't all know who Hancock is. Please can you help us by providing better context.  Who do you want to describe, the boy or Hancock? Do you want a noun or an adjective?

Comment: "superhuman" is my tongue-in-cheek answer

Comment: Sienus your right,but even superman doesn't have the ability to leave a citizen unharmed after pulling a stunt like that.Anyone would get ripped in half if they landed on him the same way.

Comment: Is one of his superpowers being incapable of hurting anyone? Then he's harmless towards humans. It's no a real power. It's fantastical. If it defies the laws of physics, it is supernatural.

Comment: Going only by the title it would be "nonpathogenic parasite".

Answer (score 1):

More suggestions...

**PARADOX**: One exhibiting inexplicable or contradictory aspects.

**ENIGMA**: One that is unfathomable, incomprehensible, mystifying.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the word **fictional**.

Another possibility is **implausible**.

Answer (score 0):

I think the word *supernatural* would fit.

Comment: Not very well: a Balrog is 'supernatural'.

Answer (score 0):

From the world of Marvel Comics comes the term **adamantium**:

> Adamantium is a fictional metal alloy appearing in American comic books published by Marvel Comics, and is best known as the substance bonded to the character Wolverine's skeleton and claws...In the stories where it appears, the defining quality of adamantium is its practical indestructibility.

([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adamantium))

The root of this term is **adamant**, from the Greek root *adámas*, “invincible”:

> 1. An imaginary rock or mineral of impenetrable hardness; a name given to the diamond and other substances of extreme hardness.
> 2. An embodiment of impregnable hardness.

([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/adamant))

And the adjectival form **adamantine** was used in literature to signify unshakableness and indestructability, notably in Milton's [Paradise Lost](https://books.google.com/books?id=6LKAaxly2lgC&pg=PA138&dq=%22adamantine%22%20%2B%20Milton&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDAQ6AEwA2oVChMIrL7R4uDqxgIVEEWICh0ayQrh#v=onepage&q=%22adamantine%22%20%2B%20Milton&f=false).

Comment: How does this cover 'but not able to allow another organism to come to harm'?

Comment: Not sure on the exact nature of the fictional substance, but apparently it is used for protection (as in Woliverine's skeleton) and not as a weapon. But who's to say it might not hurt someone who tries to punch it, etc.? This question is best left up to someone who is well-affiliated with these comics.

Comment: But isn't it the boy who is the vulnerable one?

Comment: For sure, in a world that obeys the laws of physics, both the one falling and the one catching the falling person would probably die in the circumstances described. But if one character's indestructibility is allowed, why stop there and subject the other characters to mundane physical restrictions? Once you're in the realm of Sci-Fi/Fantasy, anything goes.

Comment: See, I just don't get this. What does "Adamantium -a fictional material" have to do with the OP question?  He tells us: 1) Hancock is invincible. 2) Obviously boy is not, since he wonders how the boy is not injured. and 3) Asks for a name for this phenomenon.

Comment: OP asks for an indestructible material in the context of a fantastical world, so it seemed appropriate to suggest something--adamantium-- that itself is derived from a fantastical world. As for meeting all the OP's criteria, one would be hard pressed to find a single word that encompasses both indestructible yet harmless in the context of the traditional laws of physics, but maybe it's out there.

Comment: OP's request is for a single word to explain why the boy isn't harmed. Adamant*ium* may be a fictional material, but *adamantine* is a real word referring to adamant (although my American Heritage dictionary doesn't say that it's an *imaginary* stone.) It still doesn't explain the boy's lack of injury, but anyway, you certainly can say that Hancock is adamantine. Just wanted to clarify...

Comment: Right, and this was all implied in my answer. I try not to over-explain things so that my answer won't take up too much space.

Answer (score 0):

**fantastic** means

> a :  based on fantasy :  not real
>   b :  conceived or seemingly conceived by unrestrained fancy
>   c :  so extreme as to challenge belief :  unbelievable; broadly :  exceedingly large or great
>   ([Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fantastic))

However, if you capitalized it, you might have an argument with followers of [Marvel Comics](http://marvel.com/comics/characters/1009299/fantastic_four).

Comment: This is far too broad.

Answer (score 0):

**invincible** is the correct term here.

> incapable of being conquered, defeated, or subdued.

or **invulnerable**

> impossible to harm or damage.

Both of these terms of often used to define superhero powers.

Answer (score 0):

Given that Casey Affleck's comment is entirely to the point, I would suggest **impossible**.

I wouldn't turn up my nose at chasley's answer, either.

Answer (score -2):

**OMNIPOTENT**.   Of or having infinite power: over wind, water, physics, the laws of the universe.

The omnipotent Hancock can bend the laws of physics, gravity etc. and catch that boy unharmed.

Comment: Omnipotence is pretty good, though I'm not sure it immediately suggests "harmless" any more than _adamantine_ does. And careful with the religious connotations of omnipotence--it's most often used to describe [deities](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=omnipotent&use1913=on). But I'm not familiar with this film, and perhaps Hancock is described as godlike.

Comment: EDIT @jsoteeln  BTW I finally get it now.  Adamantine. I was thinking it was a kind of armour, or something like that, so it wasn't making much sense to me. D'oh. Omnipotence doesn't mean harmless. As to the religious aspect of the word, that is a secondary definition in my dictionary. Omni- pref. Latin, from omnis, all. You really should see the movie, it's pretty funny. Harmless or god-like he is NOT. :)    Adam...Ant...ine...   Hmm.

Comment: Puzzled by the downvotes?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Downvotes are an an accepted part of the site, and you just take them as they come. Thanks anyway for the clarifications, and for conceding a couple of points. But continuing the discussion would just be beating a dead horse.

Comment: Nope, I only conceded the one point; but it was *not* that "adamantium/adamantine" answers the OP's question in any way.  And yes, I agree; this convo has run its course.